# I have an collection of data's, I have to display the records in 3 columns in one page of an PDF in visual force

Tags: apex, apex-code, visualforce, salesforce-development

I have the collection of data in apex and i want to display the records(Visual Force) in 3 columns in one page  the flow should be filled 1 column after another column like this i want to arrange the records in 3 columns per page of an PDF

I have tried column count but it isn't working because we are iterating the collection with for each loop.
and also I have tried flow left but it arranges the record by row by row not column by column

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.